# php spl_autoload_register redaclare

Tags: php, require, spl-autoload-register

I have a question about spl_autoload_register in php.
it is namely..

```
// Use default autoload implementation
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    //==========================================
    //use foo => src\store\services\httprequest
    //==========================================
    if($class=="foo"){
        $class='src\store\services\httprequest';
    }

    $class=root.'/'.$class.'.php';

    $class=str_replace("\\","/",$class);

    require($class);

});
```

when I used 'use foo' in a class, I want the spl_autoload_register to use like src\store\services\httprequest...but it returns as redaclare.

can I solve it?

thanks for replies..

Comment: `require` to `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

[`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) - Checks if the class has been defined

Change your autoloader to first check if the class has already been loaded and then ignore it if so. The issue is that when you load the class file multiple times it will try and redeclare the class.

Doing something like this just before the `require $class` statement should fix it. Note also the usage of `false` as the second argument to prevent it autoloading itself.

```
if (class_exists($class, false)) {
    return;
}
```

I would also suggest making use of [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead. This will prevent the same file being loaded you manually load it yourself.